# USB Mouse Wakes Up My iMac Immediately After Entering Sleep Mode

Tags: usb, sleep-wake, mouse

I have a Macally Wired 3 Button Optical USB Mouse ("BUMPER MOUSE") plugged into my iMac running Mavericks. When I put my iMac to sleep, the screen goes dark, but after about 10 seconds, the red LED on the bottom of the mouse flashes rapidly for about 5 seconds, then the LED turns solid for about 2 seconds, and then the iMac wakes up.

An entry in the syslog confirms that the Macally mouse is issuing a "remote wakeup" signal:

> Jul  1 21:51:55 imac kernel[0] : Wake reason: EHC2
>
> Jul  1 21:51:55 imac kernel[0] : The USB device HubDevice (Port 1 of Hub at 0xfa000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)
>
> Jul  1 21:51:55 imac kernel[0] : AppleThunderboltHAL::earlyWake - complete - took 0 milliseconds
>
> Jul  1 21:51:55 imac kernel[0] : 169.011637: ar9300WowWakeUp: Skip PCIE WA programming
>
> Jul  1 21:51:55 iMac kernel[0] : The USB device Macally BUMPERMOUSE (Port 3 of Hub at 0xfa100000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (3)
>
> Jul  1 21:51:55 iMac kernel[0] : full wake (reason 1) 72 ms

I sent an email to Macally Tech Support but I'm not holding my breath....

Is there a setting (or script?) to tell OSX to ignore remote wakeup signal from a USB mouse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll need to unplug USB devices that wake your Mac prematurely.

This is a firmware level task which would require significant training to pull off. Nothing is impossible, but this isn't an easy setting to simply change.

Hopefully the vendor has a way to make it more like other USB mice that only wake their host when they are physically moved and not for the fun of it.